# Publish on Twitter using PHP (OAuth) Abraham Williams

Tags: php, twitter

I'm at a certain time researching how to make the publication on twitter via programming, but until then I got the code I will show below, only that even with everything set up correctly still not sending, does anyone have any suggestions for settings I must be forgetting to do so sending is completed?

Remembering that I'm using the TwiterrOAuth *Abraham Williams*, already applied for the 1.1 API. (Latest version of GIT)

Below is the code.

```
<?php

// Insert your keys/tokens

$consumerKey = 'CONSUMER';
$consumerSecret = 'CSECRET';
$OAuthToken = 'TOKEN';
$OAuthSecret = 'TSECRET';

// Full path to twitterOAuth.php (change OAuth to your own path)
require_once('twitteroauth.php');

// create new instance
$tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $OAuthToken, $OAuthSecret);

// Your Message
$message = "This is a test message.";

// Send tweet
$tweet->post('statuses/update', array('status' => "$message"));

?>
```

Have researched in several posts here on the site and brought me no solution to my problem. Remembering that you are not returning anything, just nothing happens.

My application is setup as read and write on Twitter.

The $tweet->post return false if i check it.

This is what var_dump($tweet) returns

```
object(TwitterOAuth)#1 (13) { 
["http_code"]=> int(0) 
["url"]=> string(48) "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json" 
["host"]=> string(28) "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/" 
["timeout"]=> int(30) 
["connecttimeout"]=> int(30) 
["ssl_verifypeer"]=> bool(false) 
["format"]=> string(4) "json" 
["decode_json"]=> bool(true) 
["http_info"]=> array(20) { 
    ["url"]=> string(48) "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json" 
    ["content_type"]=> NULL 
    ["http_code"]=> int(0) 
    ["header_size"]=> int(0) 
    ["request_size"]=> int(0) 
    ["filetime"]=> int(-1) 
    ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) 
    ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) 
    ["total_time"]=> float(30.02972) 
    ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.058814) 
    ["connect_time"]=> float(0) 
    ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0) 
    ["size_upload"]=> float(0) 
    ["size_download"]=> float(0) 
    ["speed_download"]=> float(0) 
    ["speed_upload"]=> float(0) 
    ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) 
    ["upload_content_length"]=> float(-1) 
    ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0) 
    ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) } 
["useragent"]=> string(25) "TwitterOAuth v0.2.0-beta2" 
["sha1_method"]=> object(OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1)#2 (0) { } 
["consumer"]=> object(OAuthConsumer)#3 (3) { 
    ["key"]=> string(22) "uqZ5yUGoofxxxxxxxxxxx" 
    ["secret"]=> string(40) "fGpJERhrIAB9RIyQEExxxxxxxxxxx" 
    ["callback_url"]=> NULL 
} 
["token"]=> object(OAuthConsumer)#4 (3) { 
    ["key"]=> string(50) "49596683-Sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
    ["secret"]=> string(40) "v3Q6pAeE4t1YXaGxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
["callback_url"]=> NULL 
} 
}
```

The $host variable.

```
public $host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ..

```
$tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $OAuthToken, $OAuthSecret)
$tweet->get('account/verify_credentials'); //<--- Add this.
```

Comment: @GabrielBuzziVenturi, I already have this working fine. What's your `var_dump` .. like `var_dump($tweet->get('account/verify_credentials'));`

Comment: return NULL, maybe its a configuration in my app that isnt right?

Comment: Well you need to var_dump your `$tweet` variable right after the new instance. So we can know what is the issue.

Comment: Return this URL https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?oauth_consumer_key=uqZ5yUGoofkwJw5zDguuWw&oauth_nonce=65be99c61f6253ade1d26171c5c00eba&oauth_signature=B5jKmLAg%2Bo4bbOnpqr3iivRVyqk%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1390561849&oauth_token=49596683-S45mVpQZUl4K64k4InC122sbtjMLtRtlnwtJqD7vw&oauth_version=1.0